# Iphone sdk - How to play a sound during a phone call after some elapsed time?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, call, nstimer

Well I am having two issues that i can't get to work, related to audio and calls.

The first one is to play a sound during a phone call. I don't want to play continuous music or stream anything, it is just a simple and short sound that the user will hear at one time during his call.

I have read some posts claiming that this is possible, and I even have an application that does so, but I can't get it to work. My app identifies the call using CTCallCenter and print the logs but never plays the sound or plays it after the app comes to foreground again. I have the .plist property of required background mode App plays audio.

The second issue, is to play the sound after some elapsed time. NSTimers doesn't work when on background mode, nor NSThread sleep on my background process or NSOperation. So how could I play this sound after say 10 seconds of the call?

Also, this behavior has to work also when the application is already on background mode. With CTCallCenter I am only getting the event when the application is interrupted from use, but I don't see any logs when i send the app to background and then begin/receive a call
.

If anyone could point me to the right direction I'll be really grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent done this, but NSLocalNotifcation, schedule a notification to play when you app get the call to move into the background. I would expect this to work. Interested to find out if it does.

Comment: Thanks I first managed to play the sound with AVToolkit, but then I realized that it is much easier with a local notification with custom sound.

Comment: I strongly doubt the Notification sound will be heard "in the phone call" to the other party. I'm very curious to know if you managed to get it to work?

Comment: @Yozef yes it is heard, have you ever received sms or whatsapp messages while in a call? they are clearly audible